# How can I get my bitizen back to work?

Tags: tiny-tower

Some of my bitizens are at their apartments, but not at the job they are assigned to, and I cannot get them back to their jobs. How do I get a bitizen back to their assigned jobs?

Answer (score 3):

Their position is purely cosmetic, it won't affect the worker's performance, no matter where they are in the tower. You can't really change their position yourself.